# How do I display two different sums of the same price with different parameters?

Tags: mysql, sql, ssms

I need to get the SUM of 2 different Totals. One is just the Total and the second one is the Total that only includes products that are sold for less than $25.

```sql
SELECT SUM(Price) AS Total
FROM Sales (NOLOCK)

SELECT SUM(Price) AS TotalUnder
FROM Sales (NOLOCK)
WHERE Price < 25
```

Expected Outcome should look like this

## |Total | TotalUnder |

| 20000 |  1500     |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(Price) AS Total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Price < 25 THEN Price ELSE 0 END) as TotalUnder
FROM Sales ;
```

Notice that I removed the `NOLOCK` hint.  This tends to be over-used and is generally not necessary.  Only use it if you really understand how SQL Server implements locking and you know what `NOLOCK` is doing.